# ionic ios10 beta permissions bug

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ios10

I just upgraded to ios10 beta on my iPhone & realized the permissions (to access photos, contacts, etc) now require a description string. I am on ionic 2

I tried adding this:

```
<config-file target="*-info.plist" parent="NSContactsUsageDescription">
<String>This is my permission string</String>
</config-file>
```

to my config.xml but that did not work.

I then tried to do it manually through XCode & now it works but I have to put the app in the background in order to get the permission popup. Is this a known bug or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I since fixed the original problem I posted in this question. I believe the issue was caused by requesting permission to the user's location before the app was completely loaded. This made the original "request location" popup appear behind the app - therefore every other permission request appeared behind the app. After moving this request to a further point in the app, the permissions popups appeared above the app.

Answer (score 7):

I would have to see your Error, but basically you now have to add things like this

camera

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Test message</string>
```

Photo Library

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Test message</string>
```

In your Appname-info.Plist

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I won't be able to test it until Tuesday when I have a mac but I'll accept the answer if it works! Have a good weekend!

Comment: This does work but every time you do ionic build ios, it zaps the entries. So I think the OP was heading towards the right direction, but I'm not sure what the answer is!

Comment: Its the camera plugin which keeps overwriting it to blank. You need to install it with variables. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#ios-quirks

Answer (score 0):

For Camera and Photo Library use this, for me it fixed everything.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="app uses camera" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="app uses library"
```